# Custom unmarshaling (in Jersey) a field in the request body into a HashMap?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, unmarshalling

I have a Jersey (1.18.1) server that currently expects say a `Person` in a POST request:

```
<person>
    <name>sdfsdfd</name>
    <age>24</age>
    ...
</person>
```

The above request body is deserialized to a Person class on my server method (say `/add`)

I need to add an `options` member to the request such that it is optional but when passed should be serialized to `Map<String, String>` member in the `Person` class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
class Person {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private int age;

    @XmlElement(required = false)
    private Map<String, String> options;

    // ctor, getters, setters etc.
}
```

I understand I have to write a custom deserializer like `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PersonOptionsAdapter.class).` What I found online regarding the adapter is to use one when the whole request body requires custom unmarshaling. However, the same does not seem to work for me for a specific member. I tried annotating the `options` member with the `PersonOptionsAdapter`,  and a few things similar.

Please share your ideas and/or solutions on how to apply a custom adapter on a specific member of the request object?

Comment: Anybody watching ??? :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way ...

This is the `JAXB` adapter that takes

```
<!-- language: java -->
@XmlRootElement
public class JaxbXml2MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, HashMap<String, String>> {

    public JaxbXml2MapAdapter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(HashMap<String, String> map) throws Exception {
        // I wasn't using it for sending this out in the response. So
        // did not bother to implement marshaling.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> unmarshal(Object rawRoot) throws Exception {
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if (rawRoot == null || !(rawRoot instanceof Element)) {
            return map;
        }

        final Element  root     = (Element) rawRoot;
        final NodeList children = root.getChildNodes();

        if (children.getLength() == 0) {
            return map;
        }

        // TODO: Analyze if there is a better way of reading the nodes.
        // Currently we get null/empty node names, white space values etc.

        for (int index = 0; index < children.getLength(); ++index) {
            final Node   child = children.item(index);
            final String name  = child.getLocalName();

            if (name == null || name.length == 0) {
               continue;
            }

            final String value = child.getTextContent();
            map.put(name, value);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Here is how to use the adapter:

```
<!-- language: java -->
@XmlRootElement(name = "myRequest")
public class MyRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String token;

    private List<int> flags = new ArrayList<int>();

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = JaxbXml2MapAdapter.class)
    private HashMap<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public MyRequest() {
    }

    // .... blah blah blah
}
```

Here is a sample request body ( *is an optional parameter*):

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<myRequest>
   <token>QWe35234</token>
   <flags>1</flags>
   <flags>4</flags>
   <options>
       <name>Johnny</name>
       <points>25.3</options>
       <someRandomStuff>sdfsgsagasfgasgsaf</someRandomStuff>
   </options>
</myRequest>
```

Hope that helps